# Dependency issues in upgrading R

Tags: upgrade, dependencies, r

I'm trying to upgrade `r` to its latest available version, but the

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

gives following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 3.0.2-1ubuntu1) but 3.3.3-1trusty0 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As the message speaks of, I have successfully installed `r-recommended` to its newest version. Still, the error prevails.

Can someone help me understand what this "but 3.3.3-1trusty0 is to be installed" means? How do I know which of the packages are broken, if any?

**dpkg broken package search through**

I have tried the following with output as shown:

```
dpkg -l | grep "r-base"
ii  libgcr-base-3-1:amd64                                 3.10.1-1                                            amd64        Library for Crypto related tasks
ii  r-base-core                                           3.3.3-1trusty0                                      amd64        GNU R core of statistical computation and graphics system
ii  r-base-dev                                            3.3.3-1trusty0                                      all          GNU R installation of auxiliary GNU R packages
ii  r-base-html                                           3.0.2-1ubuntu1                                      all          GNU R html docs for statistical computing system functions
```

dpkg system doesn't flag either of the listed packages or any other returning from `dpkg -l` as broken. I ran

```
dpkg -l | grep ^..r
```

with no matches.

Comment: askubuntu.com/a/166949/665251 Try this, this should work

Comment: None of the solutions provided in here fixes the problem. I'm updating my question to include what I've tried to diagnose broken package problem and the output.

Comment: that would be helpful